# How to create map of MAP from one list in salesforce

Tags: apex

How to create a map of MAP from list in Salesforce.

`List<sObjct> =[ID,aID,String[NJ,NY],String,String];`

i have this list above, Need to created below Map of map.

`Map<aID,Map<String[NJ,NY],List<sObjct>>>;`

Please let me know if any ideas

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
Map<Id, Map<String, SObject[]>> mapByIdByState =
  new Map<Id, Map<String, SObject[]>>();
Map<String, SObject[]> tempMap;
SObject[] tempList;
for(SObject record: listOfRecords) {
  if((tempMap = mapByIdByState.get(record.aId)) == null) {
    tempMap.put(record.aId, tempMap = new Map<String, SObject[]>());
  }
  if((tempList = tempMap.get(record.otherField)) == null) {
    tempMap.put(record.OtherField, tempList = new SObject[0]);
  }
  tempList.add(record);
}
```

In the end, you'll have a map grouped by parent Id then by State.

Comment: how to set tempMap Key here, that was one issue, the key is NJ, NY which will give diff pool

Comment: @swamiN I don't know; you've generalized your post to the point where this is just a best guess.